# Widget to enter 3 numbers that must add up to 1

Tags: sliders, dynamic-ui, widget

I need the user to select 3 numbers that add up to 1, let's call them `x`, `y`, and `z`. I could have a slider for `x` and `y`. Then `z` would simply be `1 - x - y`. But what if the user slides `x` to 1 and `y` to anything above 0? I could popup an error message, but that's not friendly...

I could shorten `y`'s slider depending on what `x`'s slider value is. Is there a better solution for this kind of widget(s)? It might be cool to have a slider with 2 tabs, which would separate the `x`, `y`, and `z` values. But I'm worried that might be confusing, particularly if one of the values is very small or 0?

[image: 3 slider widget]

Is there a good UI solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to let users adjust values that must sum to a certain number?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106356/whats-the-best-way-to-let-users-adjust-values-that-must-sum-to-a-certain-number)

Comment: @locationunknown that question’s accepted answer is the same thing I came up with! But I’m still not sure this is great given the possibility of zero or close-to-zero values…

Comment: Isn't your problem then more with how to select very small numbers (using a slider) rather than how to select numbers that add up to a certain number?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the slider when ease outwheighs the need for precision or when the values just take up a few steps on the slider. Otherwise just use input fields with some helpful labeling and validation:

Auto-fill in the last empty field:
[image]

Editing the value shows the max available:
[image]

Exceeding the max available after edit:
[image]

If you want to use the slider it just needs clearer handles that can't overlap each other:

[image]

Comment: Nice slider concept.

Comment: The answer at https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106356/whats-the-best-way-to-let-users-adjust-values-that-must-sum-to-a-certain-number is very good, but this one is perfect for zero values, very nice